# Scheme/Racket: do loop order of evaluation

Tags: racket, operator-precedence, do-loops

The following procedure is valid in both scheme r6rs and Racket:

```
;; create a list of all the numbers from 1 to n
(define (make-nums n)
  (do [(x n (- x 1)) (lst (list) (cons x lst))]
    ((= x 0)
     lst)))
```

I've tested it for both r6rs and Racket and it does work properly, but I only know that for sure for DrRacket.

My question is if it is **guaranteed** that the step expressions (`(- x 1)` and `(cons x lst)` in this case) will be evaluated in order. If it's not guaranteed, then my procedure isn't very stable.

I didn't see anything specifying this in the standards for either language, but I'm asking here because when I tested it was evaulated in order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're generally not guaranteed to be evaluated in order, but the result will still be the same.  This is because there are no side-effects here -- the loop doesn't change `x` or `lst`, it just rebinds them to new values, so the order in which the two step expressions are evaluated is irrelevant.

To see this, start with a cleaner-looking version of your code:

```
(define (make-nums n)
  (do ([x n (- x 1)] [lst null (cons x lst)])
      [(zero? x) lst]))
```

translate to a named-`let`:

```
(define (make-nums n)
  (let loop ([x n] [lst null])
    (if (zero? x)
      lst
      (loop (- x 1) (cons x lst)))))
```

and further translate that to a helper function (which is what a named-`let` really is):

```
(define (make-nums n)
  (define (loop x lst)
    (if (zero? x)
      lst
      (loop (- x 1) (cons x lst))))
  (loop n null))
```

It should be clear now that the order of evaluating the two expressions in the recursive `loop` call doesn't make it do anything different.

Finally, note that in Racket evaluation *is* guaranteed to be left-to-right.  This matters when there are side-effects -- Racket prefers a predictable behavior, whereas others object to it, claiming that this leads people to code that implicitly relies on this.  A common small example that shows the difference is:

```
(list (read-line) (read-line))
```

which in Racket is guaranteed to return a list of the first line read, and then the second.  Other implementations might return the two lines in a different order.

Comment: Edit: Thanks! That's very interesting, I didn't realize `do` worked that way.